# Hide characters in a string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, ascii

I was wondering if there was a way to hide a string of characters in a string. I found [Control Characters](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aControl_characters) which work for hidding those characters:

```
>var hidden = "\26"
undefined
>hidden
""
>hidden.replace("\26","yolo");
"yolo"
>"".replace("\26","yolo");
""
```

but what i would like to escape a string of characters and have them not show up like this:

```
>var hidden = "\26cantseethis\26"
undefined
>hidden
""
```

Is there any such method using ASCII characters?

edit:
What I am trying to do is give state to a google doc. I have a workflow type google app script attached to a form that creates a doc. the doc is immediatly viewable by the administrator so i dont want to put a bunch of special strings like &UserOneAgreed in the doc, mostly because of the potential of someone going in and modifying that string. I have another script that will go in and modify the related text once some user input is gathered.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  If you explain, someone can probably suggest an alternate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. The control character can be used for character only, so you will need to escape each character separately to hide them.